# Delete all files/folder from a folder except specific extension files

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

using Win7, I have a folder contains different sub folder and files I don't want to delete all script files whose extension is **.cs**.

Answer (score 1):

While you are asking for something to delete all non *.cs files in Batch, PowerShell may be a lot simpler:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Where {($_.Extension -ne ".cs")} | Remove-Item
```

What this does is:

- Gets all child items (files and folders) inside the current folder recursively and does so with a search limited to files.
- limits the results to files WHERE the file extension -ne (not equals) ".cs"
- Removes every result returned

be careful when using this - if your working directory is C:\, you will (attempt to) wipe every non .cs file on your disk.

To test what this will remove, add the "-WhatIf" siwtch to your syntax to perform a test run that doesn't actually remove the files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Where {($_.Extension -ne ".cs")} | Remove-Item -whatif
```

(See below using .txt extension)
[image]

Comment: where to put these lines

Comment: what do you mean "where to put these lines"?  it's a complete powershell script that can be executed through ISE or the PowerShell command line.  use cd or sl to get to your working directory and then paste the line to make it work (as shown in the screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the freeware version of DiskBoss to search for all files except files with the extension 'CS' and then delete search results. There are many different types of positive and negative file matching rules you can use to exactly specify which files to match. You can save a user-defined command and then execute such a command as many times as you wish. Also, there is a command line utility, which can be used to execute such commands from batch files and shell scripts, but the command line utility is not available in the freeware version. For more details about all the available file matching rules, refer to the following page: [DiskBoss File Search](http://www.diskboss.com/file_search.html)